# Error: Join columns must be present in data. x Problem with `column1` and `column2`

Tags: r, function

I got error for this function, when I change colum1-column3 with var1-var3 it works ,it's bizarre:

```
var1<-c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4))
var2<-c(rep("C",4),rep("D",4))
var3<-c(rep("E",2),rep("F",4),rep("G",2))
dataset<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3)


Rfun<-function(data,column1,column2,column3){

  data_<-data %>%dplyr::mutate(n = 1, {{column3}} := str_c('column3_', {{column3}})) %>% 
    complete({{column1}}, {{column2}}, {{column3}}, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = {{column3}}, values_from = n, values_fn = sum) %>% 
    mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>% 
    group_by({{column1}}) %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('column3'), 
                  ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ '0(0%)', 
                              TRUE ~ sprintf('%d(%d%%)', .,  100 * mean(. != 0)))))  %>%
    ungroup
  
  
library(vcdExtra)

   test<-CMHtest(table(data$column2, data$column3, data$column1),overall=TRUE)
   list<-c(data_,test)
   return(list)
}

Rfun(dataset,var1,var2,var3)
```

this the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your issue is the line `complete(column1, column2, column3, fill = list(n = 0))` in `Rfun()`. At this point in the function, `data` does not yet have any columns named `column1` and `column2`; whereas `column3` was defined immediately above: `mutate(..., column3 = ...)`. If you're hoping for `complete()` to see `column1` as the `var1` variable in `data`, then you need to use the syntax `{{column1}}`, as [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/u/3732271) suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249019).

Comment: This will capture the **symbol** `var1`, passed as the argument to the `column1` parameter in the call `Rfun(dataset, column1 = var1, ...)`; and it will turn the line `complete(column1, ...)` into `complete(var1, ...)` by substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `{{}}` to evaluate

```
Rfun<-function(data,column1,column2,column3){
   data %>%
    mutate(n = 1, {{column3}} := str_c('column3_', {{column3}})) %>% 
    complete({{column1}}, {{column2}}, {{column3}}, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = {{column3}}, values_from = n, values_fn = sum) %>% 
    mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>% 
    group_by({{column1}}) %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('column3'), 
                  ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ '0(0%)', 
                      TRUE ~ sprintf('%d(%d%%)', .,  100 * mean(. != 0)))))  %>%
    ungroup
    
  
  
}
```

-testing

```
Rfun(dataset,var1,var2,var3)
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  var1  var2  column3_E column3_F column3_G Total
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1 A     C     2(50%)    2(50%)    0(0%)         4
2 A     D     0(0%)     0(0%)     0(0%)         0
3 B     C     0(0%)     0(0%)     0(0%)         0
4 B     D     0(0%)     2(50%)    2(50%)        4
```

Comment: thank you :) another thing that when I integreate in the function "CMH" test and I want to print it it doesn't work:   test<-CMHtest(table(data$column2, data$column3, data$column1),overall=TRUE) print(test)

Comment: @Ruser-lab9 what is `CMH`?  If you are using this function inside another function.  May be you need to `!!` the arguments i.e. `Rfun(dataset, !!var1, !!var2, !!var3)`

Comment: I don't know how you are passing the Rfun  inside `CMHtest`

Comment: I will do an edit to the post above including CMHtest() function

Comment: @Ruser-lab9 thanks, please do